# How do I achieve a unique custom collection based on two object property together unique in java

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

How do I achieve a unique custom collection based on two object property together unique.
Suppose I have lot of custom object and I want a unique collection where the property `roll` and `s_class` together should not duplicate of any tow object in this collection.

```
class Cl {
    private int roll;
    private String s_class;
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
}
```

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, u have a collection of C1 and you want to make sure your collections doesn't have duplicates (using roll and s_class ) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly stated by @nafas you would need to use Hashset to achieve your task. And implement equals() and hashCode() in your class. Just pasting my code with some more guidelines.

```
public class Cl {

    // We should not have setter for these fields
    private int roll;
    private String s_class; 


    private String name;
    private Date dob;


    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return Objects.hash(s_class,roll);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object temp){
        if(!( temp instanceof Cl) ){
            return false;
        }
        Cl tempObj = (Cl)temp;

        String s_classTemp = tempObj.s_class;

        if(this.s_class == null && s_classTemp == null){
            return true;
        }

        if(this.s_class == null && s_classTemp != null){
            return false;
        }


        return (tempObj.roll == this.roll) && (this.s_class.equals(tempObj.s_class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using `Set<C1>` as your collection

Set doesn't contain `duplicates` so the next thing is to ensure each of your `C1` are `unique` before adding them to your set.

you need to override the `hashCode()` and `equals(Object o)` method in your class:

```
class Cl {
.
.
.

   private Integer myHash= null;

   @Override
   public int hashCode(){
       if(myHash!=null){
          return myHash;
       }
       myHash= Objects.hashCode(roll, s_class);

       return myHash;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o){
      if(o == this){
        return true;
      }

      if(o instanceOf C1){
        C1 c1 = (C1) o;
        if(c1.s_class==null){
           return c1.roll == this.roll && this.s_class == null;
        }
        else {
          return c1.roll == this.roll  && c1.s_class.equals(this.s_class);
        }
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: your answer is quite accurate. But don't you think you should have just provided the guidance and not the code? Teach a person to fish...

Comment: @Tavo mate, what I've provided is the results of 3~4 months of experiences , if you read this carefully there are many little tricks that would have taken you lots of hours to find. it wasn't a trouble for me as I just copied and paste mostly

Comment: You missed my point entirely. Learning is a process that takes many hours, I agree. But copy-pasting doesn't help anyone improving and promotes laziness. Do you think the user will bother investigating and getting to the point where he understands what he is doing and why, or will he just move forward because he doesn't have a problem anymore?

Comment: @nafas
would it be a good idea to have following null checks in equals(). 


               String s_classTemp = c1.s_class;
  if(this.s_class == null && s_classTemp == null){
   return true;
  }

  if(this.s_class == null && s_classTemp != null){
   return false;
  }